# Linq return all records from entity where a field contains one or more words from a list

Tags: c#, linq

Given a `List<string>` How to return all records in an entity that has a field containing one or more words from the list.

I tried the below which does not work and I'm starting to go around in circles a bit:

```
List<string> searchwords = new List<string>() {"word1","word2"};

var results = context.activities
    .Where(a => a.Title.Contains(searchwords.Any().ToString())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your current code:

```
var results = context.activities.Where(a => 
                  a.Title.Contains(searchwords.Any().ToString())).ToList();
```

is that you have your needle and haystack backwards. The fact that you needed to call `.ToString()` on `Any()` should have tipped you off. `Any()` returns a `bool`, which you're casting to a string, so you're just checking whether **`Title`** contains the string "True". Definitely not what you want. You want something closer to:

```
var results = context.activities
                 .Where(a => searchwords.Any(searchWord => a.Title.Contains(searchWord)));
```